# Implementation of Asynchronous Cache

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have been attempting to implement a cache which caches the results of an asynchronous method, with the restriction that I only want that method to run once for any particular item in the cache. Many other implementations I have seen allow the method to run multiple times. Although only the first returned value is actually stored, if this is a long running method, this is not desirable for me.

Storing `Task<T>` (instead of `T`) in the cache, as recommended by most implementers, is a good idea, but I still could not work out how to prevent the method that fetches the value (the valueFactory) from running more than once for any given item. The solution I came up with was to use TaskCompletionSource instead of Task for the items in the cache.

This is what I came up with:

```
public class AsyncCache<TKey, TValue>
  {
    private readonly Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueFactory;

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TaskCompletionSource<TValue>> completionSourceCache =
      new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TaskCompletionSource<TValue>>();

    public AsyncCache(Func<TKey, Task<TValue>> valueFactory)
    {
      this.valueFactory = valueFactory;
    }

    public async Task<TValue> GetItem(TKey key)
    {
      if (!completionSourceCache.TryAdd(key, new TaskCompletionSource<TValue>()))
      {
        return await completionSourceCache[key].Task;
      }

      TaskCompletionSource<TValue> taskSource = completionSourceCache[key];

      try
      {
        var result = await valueFactory(key);
        taskSource.SetResult(result);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        taskSource.SetException(e);
      }

      return await taskSource.Task;
    }
  }
```

The idea was that a key is associated with a TaskCompletionSource. The first time a particular item is requested, the TaskCompletionSource will be added to the dictionary for that key. Any subsequent (potentially reentrant) callers would be returned the Task associated with the TaskCompletionSource.

The first caller would then go on to actually call the method, and once the value was determined, this would be associated with the TaskCompletionSource, and anyone waiting on that Task would be able to view the result.

**This is my first use of TaskCompletionSource, so please tell me if you think I've missed anything, or done anything wrong.**

Note: I am aware of the ParallelExtensionsExtras AsyncCache here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/23/parallelextensionsextras-tour-12-asynccache/

but I only found this after I'd written the above! This is the only other implementation I've found with the semantics described, but since it uses Lazy, it does not *await* the result of the value factory. I'm not sure if this makes any difference though, i.e. does this mean it is not truly asynchronous, are new threads created, etc.

Comment: _I still could not work out how to prevent the task from running more than once for any given item_ What do you mean by this? Once completed a `Task` cannot be re-run. What do you need this cache for? Isn't it the same as `Task.WaitAll`? Perhaps you could add a usage example?

Comment: Sorry - I've edited the question to make it a bit clearer, hopefully. But essentially: consider if I'd had a cache of Tasks. The add to the dictionary would then look something like `dict.TryAdd(key, valueFactory(key))`. This would work, but the item is not added to the dictionary until _after_ `valueFactory(key)` completes. Thus a reentrant thread could call TryAdd a second time, and run valueFactory again. Although only one result would be added to the dictionary, it would mean that valueFactory had run twice for the same key, which is not what I want _in this case_.

Comment: Note the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626014/caching-asynchronous-operations) from the excellent @svick. This also allows the request to run multiple times. This is fine in some situations, but not what I wanted.

Comment: Thank your for explaining. I think I now understand how it works ;-)

Comment: It sounds like you want to immediately make a note that item is pending before invoking your current code. For example you might protect your `pending` dictionary with a lock, and have it map item to timestamp, which would let you timeout and retry ancient requests. Or chain subsequent tasks to depend on result from initial task.

Comment: @JH I'm not sure what you mean exactly. A `Task` object already represents something that is pending (that may complete in the future), and I am using `ConcurrentDictionary` specifically to avoid locking. Remember that you can't `await` within a lock. There's definitely a case for invalidating cache entries, but that's separate logic to adding them and I'm comfortable writing that. I'm not sure what you mean about chaining tasks either. Could you expand on that?

Comment: I thought I heard you say that a certain TKey gets queued up, and while that is pending we encounter the very same TKey, and you would prefer to coalesce them rather than handle them as a pair of distinct queries. So on the front end I was suggesting that you lock, make a note of TKey, unlock, then do your existing async processing. And on the back end I was suggesting that a single result might be delivered to (in this example) a pair of awaiting callers.

Comment: Well, I believe my code achieves that _without_ locking. What do I get from introducing a lock? I wanted to avoid locking.

Comment: Note, each key is associated with the TaskCompletionSource that represents the task for that key. There's no need to lock when adding it to the dictionary because it's a `ConcurrentDictionary`. And the `TryAdd` ensures that only one thread will ever get to the code that actually runs the task. That was my intention at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way your code is today this should work fine.  But if you ever decide to add a `RemoveItem` method you can have issues.  Since you are checking if the key exist with `TryAdd` then accessing assuming the key is there.  This works because nothing can remove a value from the `ConcurrentDictionary` as it stands.  But if you add the ability to remove an item from the `ConcurrentDictionary` then calling a `TryAdd` then assuming it's there is dangerous since the `RemoveItem` could have been processed between those statements.   This is why the `ConcurrentDictionary` has a `GetOrAdd` method to handle that situation for you.

With using a `TaskCompletionSource` you would struggle to know if you should call the factory method or not from the `GetOrAdd` since you wouldn't know if your thread was the one to add it.  This is where the `Lazy<>` version shines as it doesn't matter who added the `Lazy<Task<TValue>>` both threads can await it since it was passed in the valuefactory.

To me it would be a natural path that `RemoveItem` might be added later as most caching has a way to invalidate the cache items, for example if the `Task` threw an `Exception` maybe I want to remove it from the cache to try again.  Someone coming after to add a `RemoveItem` might not catch the subtle bug they introduced in the `AddItem` that was working.

In a nutshell it will work today but might not be as future proof as you want it to be.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. Ok, so I've made an edit which I _think_ will take care of this, using `GetOrAdd`. Hopefully I've not missed anything. It would be nice to get this working, because I'm still not sure whether the `Lazy<T>` implementation calls the factory asynchronously. I suppose there's always `AsyncLazy<T>`...

Comment: @bornfromanegg you don't need to await the factory in the lazy implantation.  It's good enough to return the task.  awaiting doesn't "start" the task that happens at creation.  awaiting just says don't do any code following the await until the task returned something.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017016/async-task-then-await-task-vs-task-then-return-task

Comment: Ah yes, of course. The Lazy implementation is looking better now the more I look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @CharlesNRice's comments, I have revised the GetItem code as follows:

```
public async Task<TValue> GetItem(TKey key)
{
  var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TValue>();
  var currentSource = completionSourceCache.GetOrAdd(key, newSource);

  if (currentSource != newSource)
  {
    return await currentSource.Task;
  }

  try
  {
    var result = await valueFactory(key);
    newSource.SetResult(result);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    newSource.SetException(e);
  }

  return await newSource.Task;
}
```

Hopefully this will address the remove issue. If `currentSource != newSource` that means that the item was already in the dictionary and we should just return that. If someone removes the item immediately after `GetOrAdd` then that's fine. We just return what we have, and if anyone else subsequently asks for the same item, it will be readded.

Comment: Also something you might want to consider if you sticking with awaiting the factory is if you need configureawait false or not.  Typically any framework code would have configureawait(false) if it doesn't need to switch back to the thread that started the await.

Comment: Yes, although presumably I wouldn't need it on the last await, since that task will always be complete by the time I await it, so my understanding is that it will just continue in the current context.